# Modificar un campo en sql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

quiero que el campo cla_cli tenga  auto incremente pero las tablas ya estan relacionadas
ya intente poniendo `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` y `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

pero sige sin funcionar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me arroja este error `#3780 - Referencing column 'cla_cli' and referenced column 'cla_cli' in foreign key constraint 'telefonos_ibfk_1' are incompatible.`

Comment: Recuerda que el tipo de datos del campo primario debe ser exactamente el mismo tipo que el campo relacionado como foráneo, así:

`cliente(cla_cli SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT`
`telefonos(cla_cli SMALLINT UNSIGNED`

Verifique que al modificar la columna no estés cambiando el tipo de `INT` a `SMALLINT` por ejemplo.

Comment: gracias........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proba esto

```
ALTER TABLE cliente DROP FOREIGN KEY telefonos_ibfk_1;
```

eso borrara la clave foranea y asi podras editar lo que quieres luego deberas volver a crearla